# How do I send Styled Text using Java Mail?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am implementing JavaMail API to send an email.

I want to provide text formatting options like Bold, Italics and Underline.I am done with formatting in JTextPane using StyledEditorKit but now I wanted this styled text and send it through an email.

The JTextPane returns a StyledDocument object and I don't know how to use that to send the styled text via email.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#sendrich).

Simple answer - send html text.